# O(n) Fibonacci?

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, fibonacci-sequence

I attempted to write an \$O(N)\$ Fibonacci.

```
fibMemo :: Integer -> Map Integer Integer -> Integer
fibMemo n map
 | n == 0    = 0
 | n == 1    = 1
 | otherwise = case maybeMember of Just x  -> x
                                   Nothing -> calced
               where maybeMember = M.lookup n map
                     calced      = fibMemo (n-1) map + fibMemo (n-2) map
```

My understanding is that it's \$O(N)\$ since I think, worst case, it takes \$N\$ calls to `fibMemo` in order to compute `fibMemo(N)`.

Please critique my Haskell implementation, as well as answer the `O(N)` question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not caching the results, so `fibMemo` is \$O(2^n)\$.

More precisely, `fibMemo n` will result in \$2F_{n + 1} - 1\$ calls to `fibMemo`, where \$F_n\$ is the \$n\$th Fibonacci number.

To prove this, let \$T(n)\$ be the total number of calls to `fibMemo` required to evaluate `fibMemo n`. Then

\begin{align}
T(0) &= 1 = 2F_1 - 1, \\
T(1) &= 1 = 2F_2 - 1,
\end{align}
which are our base cases. In the general case,

\begin{align*}
T(n + 1) &= 1 + T(n) + T(n - 1) \\
     &= 1 + (2F_{n + 1} - 1) + (2F_{n} - 1) \quad \text{(by the induction hypothesis)} \\
     &= 2(F_{n + 1} + F_{n}) - 1 \\
     &= 2F_{n + 2} - 1.
\end{align*}

You can get timing information using `:set +s` in GHCI, which gives a pretty strong hint that it's not \$O(n)\$:

```
*Main> :set +s
*Main> fibMemo 20 M.empty
6765
(0.08 secs, 18282888 bytes)
*Main> fibMemo 30 M.empty
832040
(3.81 secs, 1092375120 bytes)
```

Comment: So 2^n since fibMemo (N) requires 2^n calls to fibMemo? Also isn't the map caching?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Nothing is being inserted into the map, so no caching is being done. \$O(2^n)\$ is not a tight bound, but yes the number of calls to `fibMemo` is exponential in \$n\$. You can find an analysis [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/360773/1220238).

Comment: But my `fibsImproved'` is O (n), https://github.com/kevinmeredith/brentyorgey_upenn_class_hw/blob/master/Homework6/Fib.hs?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I believe so, yes.